# How to capturing packets and analyzing the SDN network using Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, sdn, mininet

I am new in the world of network. I work in SDN field and I have a POX    controller with a mininet. I need to capture the packets in the network using Apache Spark and then analysis them. By now I use Wireshark to capture packets and do analysis on them in Spark. However I think that Spark itself has capability of capturing the streaming packets. I search on this topic but unfortunately I could not find a good and clear code or method on it. Can any body help me more clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using POX, you can use events generated by pox to start process packets. For example, you can handle packetin event so you know every time a packet arrives the controller.

you can also install some rules to count those packets based on some criteria.

if you want to process all packets in the network then you need to connect your tool (I don't know spark) to the mininet network.

good luck

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, exactly I need to do some machine learning on packets and network, that is why I needed it. By now I decided to capture the packets by Wireshark and do the analysis in Spark. However I don't think that it is an efficient way.